# Making a small program part as a bigger one in java. Multithreading?. Noobs

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am working on a small project where I have to communicate to an Android app on my phone and with Arduino.

Now, I have the connection between Android and laptop (used as server, I have a small amount of data stored here), and I can change the contents of text files when I send certain instructions from Android app.

This is how I do it:

I have a `ServerSide` class that listens on port 3000 and I read the text I stream from phone, then I make certain changes in text files for different messages.

The code:

```
public class ServerSide {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    while (true) {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        // check if client is trying to connect
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot communicate on this port");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;

        // move to another socket
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // stream that will be sent to client. "true" is for creating from
        // existing
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),
                true);
        // stream that comes from the client
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String recivedData, sendData;

        ServerProtocol communicationProtocol = new ServerProtocol();

        while ((recivedData = in.readLine()) != null) {

            sendData = communicationProtocol.process(recivedData);
            out.println(sendData);
            System.out.println("The text should now be written in file");
            System.out.println(sendData);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();

    }

}

}
```

`ServerProtocol.process()` is the method that updates the files

By the way, this is a good version of a program that implies connection via sockets (if anyone should need information about this, at a future time).

Everything works great, I can see my updates immediatly after I send them, the server is up and running, waiting for messages.

I forgot to mention, I am new to java and a novice in programming, in general.

Now, I want this code I managed to write to be part of a bigger "server". By "server", I understand a program that "serves", performs a service. When it runs on my laptop, it takes information that comes from the Internet on the port I specify, change things in files according to my messages, keeps theese files updated and in the same time it uses theese files to "interpert" data I send from phone, and then sends according messages to Arduino Shield.   (THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIVE)

I guess that what I miss, is the following:

**How do i make this code I have written untill now, part of a bigger project, that does all that?**

I managed to split the project in 3 parts:

1. Communication laptop - Android
2. Constant data updates
3. Communication laptop - Arduino

I've done some research, and I came across threads. So I thought about having the communication with Android on a separate thread of a `MainServer`. I clearly got it wrong, because it doesn't do what I expect it to do, so here is the code:

I create the `ServerSide` class that extends Thread, and has a `run()` method that should be called when I start the thread. It behaves just like the one above, but the executing code lays inside a `run()` method:

```
public class ServerSide extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        // check if client is trying to connect
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot communicate on this port");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;

        // move to another socket
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // stream that will be sent to client. "true" is for creating from
        // existing
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // stream that comes from the client
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String recivedData, sendData;
        recivedData = null;
        sendData = null;

        ServerProtocol communicationProtocol = new ServerProtocol();

        try {
            while ((recivedData = in.readLine()) != null) {

                try {
                    sendData = communicationProtocol.process(recivedData);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                out.println(sendData);
                System.out
                        .println("The text should now be written in file");
                System.out.println(sendData);
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.close();
        try {
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then, I have the `MainServer`:

```
public class MainServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Started");
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new ServerSide());
    myThread.start();
    System.out.println("Started2");

    while (true);
    }
    }
```

It should do nothing, just start the new thread. I expect this new thread do act just like the old `ServerSide` above (the one with `main()` method).

Someone, please tell me where I got it wrong !?!

Comment: I bet this is a compilation error. Tell me what it is if I'm right

Comment: No, the problem seems to be a different one, and I will now start new reaserch. It only happenes once: if I compile ServerSide and MainServer, then run MainServer, it acts as desired. BUT, if I close MainServer and restart it, it doesn`t do anything. I think I should stop the thread (?)

Comment: Threads seem pretty confusing for you. If you stop the `MainServer`, all threads it starts should be stopped.

Comment: That`s what I expect too... At the moment I don`t understand why it works only after running first time after compiling

Comment: Me neither. I can't help you.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but it seems that everything works ok, except my wireless router. The connection with Android is made via router, and I am in the back yard, where signal on laptop works ok, but the signal on phone is on the border line. It works with ups and downs, so in fact, when "nothing changed" I was not sending data. Sorry for the quetion, and your time

Comment: What you might do is post that as an answer, then accept it, so nobody wastes any time looking at a solved problem.

Comment: This was the first time to write something on stackoverflow, could you please give some instructions on this?

Comment: Wait seven hours, then click the button at the bottom of the page to add your solution as an answer. Then wait two days and click the green checkmark under the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was OK here, my problem was actually my phone connection to wi-fi, I was a bit too far in the back yard :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, two things seem a little unusual about the `MainServer` class. First, creating a thread with `new Thread(new ServerSide())` will cause a compilation error. There are two ways to fix this: either you make `ServerSide` implement the `Runnable` interface instead of extending `Thread`, or you create the thread with `new ServerSide()`. Second, the infinite loop at the end of `main` is useless and can be removed. The main method runs in its own thread, and if it finishes, all other threads keep running, and there is no need to keep main alive. The program will indeed keep running when `main` finishes, which may seem strange, but that's what will happen.

Comment: 1.I know that while loop is useless, I just use it because this should happen while my server is active. That is not a matter of interest, right now.

2.MainServer seems to work, but only once. I compile both ServerSide  and MainServer, then run MainService (java -classpath . MainServer), and it works fine. When I stop it and start it again, it just waits. Should I stop my thread at exit? How?